# Sort a generator using generators?

Tags: python, sorting, functional-programming, generator

I have a lot of data stored in generators, and i would like to sort them without using lists, to not go out of memory in the process. It's possible to sort the generators by this way?. I have some hours thinking this and i can't find a way to do it without saving the seen values somewhere (or there's a way saving them "partially"). I have read in google about lazy sorting, is that a nice approach? Thanks for the answers!!

EDIT: My final objective is to write all the sorted data to a file.

PS: sorry about my bad english ><

Comment: Where is the data coming from and what kind of data is it?

Comment: from csv and txt files, are generally ints, floats, strs.

Comment: You might also want to look into [external sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting), which nowadays seem somehow forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

You should just write the data to  your output file in non-sorted order, then sort it on the filesystem.  If you're on Linux this is easily and very efficiently done using [`sort(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html).  Or if you want to do it within Python, try [`csvsort`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/csvsort/1.0) which is specifically designed for this.